# Need to Fix Data truncation issue in Apache NiFi while Importing DB data from MS SQL DB to Load in Redshift DB

Tags: amazon-redshift, apache-nifi

I am using **Apache NiFi 1.24.0** version and trying to load data from MS Sql DB to AWS Redshift DB.

Got all processor are working and its loading data in Redshift DB, except it truncate some records while fetching it through QueryDatabaseTableRecords in CSV format.
For example: If we have 12 records in DB table, then it only fetch only 11 records through CSV file and load  in target DB, again if we have 4406 records in anther table then it will fetch only 4204 records and this way it will skip more then 202 records while loading data in target table.
So need to fix this data truncation issue.

For above below are NiFi processor are used, I.e.
`QueryDatabaseTableRecords (to Fetch source DB records) --> UpdateAttribute(to convert Date function)--> PutDatabaseRecord (To load data in Redshift DB also I have given Statement type Insert in this particular processor.)`

Also I want to truncate records while re-loading data in same table through NiFi processor for that I tried to use ExecuteSqlRecord and given truncate statement for that particular table in Sqlselectquery under ExecuteSqlRecord but its failing by giving FK constraint issue.

So purpose is First time Data need to insert in target DB while second time when same records go to insert first it should truncate and then load to avoid duplicate records.

Any idea how to fix above issue?

For above below are NiFi processor are used, I.e.
`QueryDatabaseTableRecords (to Fetch source DB records) --> UpdateAttribute(to convert Date function)--> PutDatabaseRecord (To load data in Redshift DB also I have given Statement type Insert in this particular processor.)`

Also I want to truncate records while re-loading data in same table through NiFi processor for that I tried to use ExecuteSqlRecord and given truncate statement for that particular table in Sqlselectquery under ExecuteSqlRecord but its failing by giving FK constraint issue.